# Springboot, Hibernate, Spring Data JPA - unable to log in

Tags: hibernate, security, authentication, jpa, spring-boot

I've been following this example to create a login feature on my site:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XO-OdIXNU_o

However my login attempts are failing. From the stacktrace, a user is found with username "test" but the credentials are coming up as wrong (I've tried the password both with and without encryption and had the same error.

**This is my WebSecurityConfig.java file:**

```
package com.sitename.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import  org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

import org.slf4j.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = CustomUserDetailsService.class)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {    
     auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
 } 

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/logout").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/users/login") 
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .successHandler(successHandler())
                //.failureHandler(failureHandler())
                .permitAll();

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        log.info("Login success!");
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        handler.setUseReferer(true);
        return handler;
    }

    //    @Bean
    //    public AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler() {
    //      log.info("Login failure - bad credentials");
    //      return failureHandler();
    //    }

   @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        log.info("Running configureGlobal method in WebSecurityConfig");
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
//        auth
//            .inMemoryAuthentication()
//                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean(name="passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**This is my User Entity:**

```
package com.sitename.domain.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@NotBlank
@NotEmpty
@NotNull
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@NotBlank
@NotEmpty
@NotNull
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@NotBlank
@NotEmpty
@NotNull
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@NotBlank
@NotEmpty
@NotNull
@Column(name = "enabled")
private int enabled;

public User(String username, String password, String email, int enabled) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public User(User user) {
    this.id = user.id;
    this.username = user.username;
    this.email = user.email;
    this.password = user.password;
    this.enabled = user.enabled;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public int getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(int enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}


public User() {}

}
```

**My UserRole entity:**

```
package com.sitename.domain.models;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;

@Column(name = "role")
private String role;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

}
```

**My UserRepository:**

```
package com.sitename.domain.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.sitename.domain.models.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

public User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**My UserRoleRepository:**

```
package com.sitename.domain.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.sitename.domain.models.UserRole;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface UserRoleRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRole, Long> {

@Query("select a.role from UserRole a, User b where b.username=?1 and a.id=b.id")
public List<String> findRoleByUsername(String username);
 }
```

**My CustomUserDetails class:**

```
package com.sitename.security;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import com.sitename.domain.models.User;

public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<String> userRoles;

public CustomUserDetails(User user, List<String> userRoles) {
    super(user);
    this.userRoles = userRoles;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    String roles=StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(userRoles);           
    return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(roles);
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return super.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return super.getUsername();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

**My CustomUserDetailsService class:**

```
package com.sitename.security;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import org.slf4j.*;

import com.sitename.domain.models.User;
import com.sitename.domain.repositories.UserRepository;
import com.sitename.domain.repositories.UserRoleRepository;

@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

@Autowired
public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository, UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.userRoleRepository = userRoleRepository;
}


@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    log.info("Username entered: " +  username);
    if(user.equals(null)) {
        log.info("User with username: " + username + " not found.");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username: " + username);
    } else {
        log.info("User found with username " + user.getUsername() + " and password " + user.getPassword());
        List<String> userRoles = userRoleRepository.findRoleByUsername(username);
        return new CustomUserDetails(user, userRoles);
    }
}


}
```

**Application.properties:**

server.port: 9000

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sitename
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**Main class:**

```
package com.sitename;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.sitename.domain.repositories")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.sitename.domain.models")
public class WebsiteApplication {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebsiteApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WebsiteApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

I think it may be an error with the Hibernate query, due to the "where username=?" part of the log, as opposed to where username="test" but I don't know HQL so i could be wrong there.

Here is the part of the log that appears when I try to log in:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.email as email2_1_, user0_.enabled as enabled3_1_, user0_.password as password4_1_, user0_.username as username5_1_ from users user0_ where user0_.username=?
[2m2016-03-12 16:41:37.487[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3420[0;39m [2m---[0;39m     [2m[nio-9000-exec-8][0;39m [36mc.d.security.CustomUserDetailsService   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Username entered: test
[2m2016-03-12 16:41:37.487[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3420[0;39m [2m---[0;39m     [2m[nio-9000-exec-8][0;39m [36mc.d.security.CustomUserDetailsService   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m User found with username test and password $2a$10$Lrp4kzL12tC.p0Ut7i92oeZzXn9WCplba1iPoJxAXRysxQ2dwvFxq
Hibernate: select userrole0_.role as col_0_0_ from user_roles userrole0_ cross join users user1_ where user1_.username=? and userrole0_.id=user1_.id
```

I've also noticed that the successHandler() method is run on start up (it appears in the log) - not sure if this is normal.

Thank you very much for any help!